# Show that there is a unique morphism $E_{c}: R[x] \rightarrow R^{\prime}$ with $E_{c}(r)=r$ for all $r \in R$ and $E_{c}(x)=c$

Tags: abstract-algebra, polynomials, ring-theory, solution-verification

I'm doing Exercise 5 in textbook Algebra by Saunders MacLane and Garrett Birkhoff.

[image]

> If a ring $R$ is not commutative, an element $c$ is called central in $R$ if $c r=r c$ for every $r \in R$. Construct from $R$ a ring $R[x]$ containing $R$ as a subring and a central element $x$ such that to any ring $R^{\prime}$ with a central element $c$ and containing $R$ as a subring there is a unique morphism $E_{c}: R[x] \rightarrow R^{\prime}$ with $E_{c}(r)=r$ for all $r \in R$ and $E_{c}(x)=c$.

Could you please verify if my attempt is fine or contains logical mistakes? Thank you so much for your help!

---

Let $R[x]$ be the set of all sequences $p:\mathbb N \to R$ such that $\{n \in \mathbb N \mid p_n \neq 0\}$ is finite. For $p,q \in R[x]$, we define addition and multiplication by $$\begin{aligned} (p + q)_n &= p_n+q_n \\ (p  q)_n &= \sum_{k=0}^{n} p_{k} q_{n-k}\end{aligned}$$

It's then straightforward to verify that $R[x]$ is a ring. Define $x \in R[x]$ by $x_n = 1$ if $n = 1$ and $x_n = 0$ otherwise. Then $x$ is a central element of $R[x]$. Furthermore, $x^k := \underbrace{x\cdots x}_{k \text{ times}}$ is such that $(x^k)_n = 1$ if $n = k$ and $(x^k)_n = 0$ otherwise. We identify $a \in R$ with $p \in R[x]$ for which $p_n = a$ if $n=0$ and $p_n = 0$ otherwise. It follows that $p \in R[x]$ can be represented uniquely as $p= \sum_n p_n x^n$.

Consider the map $E_c:R[x] \to R', \sum_n p_n x^n \mapsto \sum_n p_n c^n$. By construction, this is the unique morphism satisfying the required conditions.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This looks good to me! You didn't prove all of your claims (and as a result you didn't explicitly use all of the assumptions – e.g. you never mentioned the fact that $c$ is central), but it's clear you understand what's going on so I'm sure you could. In any case, this is absolutely the correct construction.

Comment: IMHO, the fact that $c$ is central in $R'$ is irrelevant here :))

Comment: It is not! $c$ must commute with all elements of $R$, or else the map is not a ring homomorphism at all!

Comment: Oh I see, it is essential in proving that $E_c$ preserves multiplication structure. Thank you for correcting my misunderstanding. That's so great!

Comment: Exactly :) glad I could help